# "to disrupt Thompson from discharging his duty to approve the count of votes"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Currently reading [**this article about Trump**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/legal-troubles-loom-over-trump-after-presidency-021009145.html), there is a line,

> The Feb. 16 suit says the defendants **tried to disrupt Thompson from discharging his duty to approve the count of votes cast by the Electoral College after the presidential election.**

I somewhat find this bold part strange personally.

So, Trump tried to "disrupt"="annoy" Mr.Thompson, from setting his duty free to approve the court of votes case by the Electoral College.

Where am I wrong here?

Comment: I think the slightly "odd" usage here is ***disrupt*** (which doesn't mean ***to annoy*** - it means [***to prevent something, esp. a system, process, or event, from continuing as usual or as expected***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disrupt)). The reason I find it a bit odd is that (as per by that definition) we normally expect the syntactic ***object*** of the verb to be the (adversely affected) ***activity / process***, not the person/people who would have performed that activity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry for my mistake (=disrupt=annoy), but thanks to Old Brixtonian's answer I was able to grasp the whole image and what is wrong. And thank you for the additional info to you too.

Comment: Imagine a context where you start talking to someone who's currently (mentally) engaged doing something that demands most of their attention (ticking off items on a shopping list by checking that they are in the trolley, for example). They might use colloquial / idiomatic *Don't **put me off** while I'm checking the list*, or *Don't **distract me...***, but they probably wouldn't say *Don't **disrupt me...*** Note that ***distract*** - to ***turn someone's attention away*** (from what they *should* be concentrating on) 
 - only works for my example, not your Trump piece.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, but I think core issue is the usage of "discharge" ( which typically mean set someone free ). the word shouldnt've been used there. By the way, it's not what Trump say, it's about what the very writer wrote.

Comment: Nah - you're mistaken about ***discharge***. Which actually *rarely* means "to set someone free", but it comes close to that sense in contexts like *He was discharged from hospital after treatment*. The usage ***to discharge one's responsibilities*** is *extremely* standard in formal contexts, where it means ***perform, carry out*** (by metaphoric extension from the underlying more literal ***to release from an obligation*** - by ***doing*** something, so it ***no longer needs*** to be done). Note that my "a Trump piece" means "a piece **about** Trump", not **by** him.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Then how come the synonym dictionary covers almost in a sense "set someone free"? I use synonym dictionary as a handy dictionary. I got it about piece thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please see [ https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/discharge ]

Comment: @FumbleFingers Anyways, the verb "discharge" is/was difficult to me. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a competent native Anglophone, and you're not. The word ***discharge*** has a wide range of meanings, but your link to a list of possible synonyms for the ***noun*** sense is unhelpful and misleading, because it's ***relatively uncommon*** for ***discharge*** to be used as a noun with the relevant meaning in your cited text (***discharge = fulfilment, performance, or execution of an obligation, duty, function***, being the relevant definition from the full Oxford English Dictionary).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please click to the right side and you will find the synonym of the verb meanings. i concur with your "the word discharge has a wide range of meanings".

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are not competent enough!. haha sorry joking. Of course I'm no match to you regarding English.

Comment: Obviously you are no match for me if we're disagreeing about what some English word means! But this shouldn't be a "competition" anyway - the situation here is that I know something that you want to *also* know (*and* I actually want you to know the same things that I do). Mind you, I also learn stuff about English as a result of being here on ELL. I was surprised to find just how many different senses ***discharge*** has, AND how complex and uncertain the origins of the word are (but I think it basically centres around an "original" sense of ***unload** a burden*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, I agree with your that wide range part completely. Unload as an origin? Could be. Sorry I got to go to bed be reminded I ridiculed you you didn't click to the right side. See you. Thank you anyway(m_m).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think my answer had already pointed out the slightly odd usage of *disrupt*. And it gave the relevant meaning of "discharge". Was there something in there you disagreed with?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: No, there certainly wasn't anything in your answer I disagreed with. I'd already upvoted it before I started typing my first comment. For one reason or another, I didn't actually see the "BTW" section of your answer until after composing and posting the comment. It's true I wouldn't have written the comment at all if I'd been more on the ball about reading *your* contribution, but when I realised the situation *after the fact*, it seemed reasonable to let it stand. If only because I did actually include a link to the relevant definition for the OP if he wanted to use it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Oh good! Yes - quite right about the link. I enjoy your comments. Thanks for splaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the word 'discharge' that's tripping you up.

The third definition of the word at [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/discharge) is:

> Do all that is required to perform (a duty) or fulfil (a
> responsibility)
>  **‘the bank had failed to discharge its supervisory
> duties’**

So it was Thompson's duty to approve the count. The defendants tried to disrupt the process.

BTW, there are mistakes in the English here. We don't disrupt some**one**: we disrupt some**thing**. And we certainly don't disrupt someone **from** doing something, though we might **deter** them from doing it.

So (according to the suit) they *did* disrupt the proceedings and they did try to *prevent* the approval of the count.